# changing drive nodes & hdparm

Tags: startup, disk

I am currently attempting to create a command that works at startup to kill the power on two of my very noisy hard drives. I have edited the `etc/rc.local` file to include this command:

```
sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdc 
sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdd

exit 0
```

While I think this should work, it seems the allocated drives keep switching around every time I reboot. I have `sda`, `sdb`, `sdc`, `sdd`, and `sde` but they keep getting jumbled around (making the drive I wish to shut different than `sdd` which is making the task of shutting down the right drive on start-up quite cumbersome.

I had a perfectly functioning ftstab file working which disappeard, but I restored it from the back up into the `etc/` dir:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>


#Entry for /dev/sda1 :
UUID=43c09daf-08a5-44f2-89b0-fc7c6f0d1e67    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1
#Entry for /dev/sdd1 :
UUID=443AFBAD7FE50945    /media/DX100    ntfs-3g    defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_CA.UTF-8    0    0
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=FCE456F5E456B21E   /media/GalaxyM83    ntfs-3g    defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_CA.UTF-8    0    0
#Entry for /dev/sdf1 :
UUID=1CA057FDA057DBB8    /media/Holideck    ntfs-3g    defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_CA.UTF-8    0    0
#Entry for /dev/sdc1 :
UUID=7ABB49654B799D40    /media/JX3P    ntfs    defaults,nosuid,nodev,locale=en_CA.UTF-8    0    0
```

it seems every time I boot the order of the drives changes. I do not know how to resolve this. A quick workaround the problem was to go with UUID instead of the DEV letter by editing the etc/rc.local file to include:

> hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/443AFBAD7FE50945
>
> hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/7ABB49654B799D40

So I thought I was in the clear, as I heard both hard drives die down during the boot sequence, BUT, as soon as I log in both drives start up again! so now I have to figure out what is making them start up again after log in, or perhaps another way to get them to turn off. Is there some kind of command i can get to execute after log in? I tried editing the startup applications to include an autossh with:

> autoshh - sudo hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/7ABB49654B799D40
> autoshh - sudo hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/443AFBAD7FE50945

but this did not seem to work to turn off the disks after log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the disk you are trying to shut down contains an NTFS partition. Find out what is the volume label, in my example below I will use label DATA. Then you could use script like:

```
for drive_letter in {a..f} ; do 
  if [ "`ntfslabel /dev/sd${drive_letter}1`" == "DATA" ] ; then 
    sudo hdparm -y /dev/sd${drive_letter}1
  fi
done
```

*Explanation*

- `for drive_letter in {a..f} ; do` loops over letters a-f
- ``` if [ "``ntfslabel /dev/sd${drive_letter}1``" == "DATA" ] ; then ``` checks the label of device /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1, etc and compares it to DATA (sorry about the double backticks)
- `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sd${drive_letter}1` is the payload

Comment: @smurf thank you for your reply, but I do not know even where to begin with all this. it looks VERY confusing (i am relatively new to UBUNTU). What i have done already with teh help of Rinzwind is to edit the HDPRAM.CONF file


 {
hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/443AFBAD7FE50945
}

{
hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/7ABB49654B799D40
}

Comment: this seemed to get the two disks i wanted to shut down off, but as soon as I log on, they turn on agian. = (

Comment: murf thank you for your reply, but I do not know even where to begin with all this. it looks VERY confusing (i am relatively new to UBUNTU). What i have done already with the help of Rinzwind is to edit the HDPRAM.CONF file which didnt work so I edited the rc.local file. I have edited teh question above to include more than was originally posted. I am not sure if your answer is still pertinent?